# Get parent node name in anytree

Tags: python, tree, anytree

I have created a tree using anytree for my custom taxonomy and I am able to search the tree using:

```
from anytree import find
name='c'
find(root, lambda node: node.name == name)
```

This returns an object of Node class that looks something like this:

```
Node('/f/b/d')
```

So, for child c, d is the immediate parent and I just want to extract `'d'` and not the entire path mentioned above.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I don't know `anytree` but maybe it could search `node.next.name == name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `.parent.name`

You can even get grandparent name `.parent.parent.name` (if only exists)

```
from anytree import Node
from anytree import find

root = Node("f")
b = Node("b", parent=root)
d = Node("d", parent=b)
c = Node("c", parent=d)

name='c'
result = find(root, lambda node: node.name == name)

print('result Node:', result)

if result.parent:
    print('parent name:', result.parent.name)

if result.parent and result.parent.parent:
    print('grandparent:', result.parent.parent.name)
```

Result:

```
result Node: Node('/f/b/d/c')
parent name: d
grandparent: b
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Three things to note:

1. you can cast `anytree.Node` to a `string`
2. the first 6 characters of the stringified Node class is always `Node('` and the last 2 characters are always `')`
3. the `anytree.Node` class has a `separator` attribute which you can use to split the stringified `Node` on

Combining these facts:

```
In [7]: node
Out[7]: Node('/A/C')

In [8]: str(_next)[6:-2].split(_next.separator)[-1]
Out[8]: 'C'
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. @furas answer is more accurate and what i was looking for :)